# How can I calculate the probability of a person being shot on daily basis in US?

Tags: probability

Just a random idea from me is that I would like to know what is the probability of me being shot per day when I'm out for work. Under the context of so far, there have been 293 mass shootings from the beginning of this year to 10/27 this year.  I've taken university level of math classes including the intro. to probability theory but still would like some pointing of directions to help myself start the reasoning and calculation of this. Or is this totally not calculable due to lack of information? If so please point out what is the basic information I need to collect. Thanks!

Comment: There is a tremendous lack of information here.  The assumption that any one person is just as likely as any other to be a victim of a shooting is invalid... people who engage in illegal activities are far more likely to be shot than otherwise.  On the other extreme, someone who spends all day in their own home and never leaves for any reason is far less likely to be shot.  You would also need to make an assumption as to whether or not current trends continue which is a dangerous assumption to make as well.

Comment: So what if I allow 0 probability to make my invalid assumption valid, can I calculate regardless the tendency from life styles?

Comment: If you were to make an incredibly naive estimation which assumes uniformity and independence of occurrences (*which again are not at all safe assumptions whatsoever*), you might take the number of observed victims over a time frame, divide by the total population size and the number of days in the length of the time frame to get an estimated probability that a randomly selected person is a victim on a randomly selected day.

Comment: A person who got shot for three or more days in a row would likely begin to stay inside and hide.

Comment: @WillJagy +1 as you made me laugh XD

Comment: @AnkitKumar It made me laugh as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this link](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-41488081), there were 14,415 gun homicides in 2016, which amount to 14,415/366 ~ 39 deaths per day. The current population of the United States is about 325 million. So, *other things being equal*, the probability that on a given day you personally will be shot to death is about 39 divided by 325 million, or 1 in 8.3 million.